# Fix Ordering in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to limit the ordering of a dictionary but the ouput that I get are returned in a sorted order which is something I do not want.

```py
test = {}
test['bbb'] = '0'
test['aaa'] = '1'
# Returns me {'aaa': '1', 'bbb': '0'} when I am expecting {'bbb': '0', 'aaa': '1'}
```

The above is a simple example, in which both `aaa` and `bbb` are queried from a list. And I had thought this may have resolves the ordering but it did not.

Comment: Do you want it ordered or not, unclear from the question. In Python 3.6 and up you will have it ordered as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is not preserving the order of added elements. You need to use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead to have this feature available.

Comment: Dictionaries have been ordered by default since 3.6x.

Comment: I know and had this mentioned in earlier revision of my answer, but I removed that intentionally.